How to make github copilot for VScode use entire workspace for inline suggestions
According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/copilot/prompt-crafting, Copilot only uses open files to generate inline suggestions - is there a way to make it consider all files in the workspace? I am NOT talking about Copilot Chat (which seems to have taken over google when searching for this issue...), I'm talking about the old-fashioned super-useful inline suggestion plug-in.
If there's no such way, I'll put in a feature request, it's silly to have to open a hundred files to make it scour them for context...
